# Save SharedPreferences from TextView

Tags: android, textview, sharedpreferences

I am making an app were I want to save the text of a TextView in SharedPreferences. I want the SharedPreferences to be updated when the TextView is changed.

Comment: It is possible. It would be same like adding preferences, instead of hardcode, take textbox value. Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend something along these lines:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                int count)
    {
      prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();
    }

    @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                    int after)
    {
    }

    @Override
      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    }
  });
```

Comment: How do I use the preference from another class?

Comment: not sure what you're asking, do you mean how do you use this text value you've auto-saved? or do you mean something else?

Comment: I do not think I need a text watcher. I just need to save the TextView. I think I can update it using a onClickListener.

Comment: you could do the `prefs.edit().putString("autoSave", s.toString()).commit();` anywhere you like

Comment: @dldnh i have a similar question also. I want to save the text of a Edit Text in SharedPreferences. I want the SharedPreferences to be updated when the text from Edit Text is changed.I am using the code u presented but when i restarts the application,the changed text is not there. Can u suggest me what i am doing wrong